# How do I get my bot to react with custom emotes?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm currently using something similar to this:

```
String emote = event.getJDA().getEmoteById("emoteAlias:guildId").getAsMention();
            event.getMessage().addReaction(emote).queue();
```

I've tried it in many different ways, using different syntax and also using emote ids instead of the alias and guild id (as I was instructed to do so elsewhere).

When trying to run this, it says it expects a valid long value. I've tried just giving the long value of the emote id. Didn't work.

Can someone please show me how the syntax for this snippet should look?

Also, I have tried reading the documentation. It really isn't very clear and doesn't show examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getEmoteById` accepts the raw id itself. `emoteAlias:guildId` is not a way to reference emotes since you can have multiple emotes with the same name in the same guild. You can get an emote id by posting it in a discord channel with `\:name:` which will result in a format like `<:name:id>`.

You don't need the `Emote` instance to add a reaction. You can directly pass the reaction code to the method like `addReaction("name:id")`:

1. Post emote in a chat. Note this is not the "guild id" but the emote name and id. Emotes have their own IDs just like messages.

[image]

[image]

2. Make the emote a constant in your code

```java
public class Emotes {
    public static final String VIM = "vim:414776062380343296";
}
```

3. Use the emote in your `addReaction` call

```java
channel.addReaction(Emotes.VIM).queue();
```